# Migrating to swift 3.1 from swift 2.3 issues

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, updates

I'm trying to move a Framework used by a work app, to swift 3.1 from swift 2.3. I'm having some problems like:

```
error: module 'Alamofire' has no member named 'SessionManger'
    self.alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManger(configuration: configuration)
```

And it seems that is only Alamofire complaining, I have installed pod 4.5 there is a SessionManager, I have deintegrated and installed the pods again, clean the project so on. Still no luck. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
self.alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```

Notice the extra "a".

Comment: Thanks I did not saw that, dumb mistake :)